# Find command with ZSH based on a list of files

Tags: find, zsh

I was used to running BASH but I recently discovered ZSH and I have to say that it works well. However I have a problem with the find instruction below.

Let's say we have 3 webp files and one listing.txt with 2 lines 1.* and 3.* because I'd like to rename their extension from .webp to .webp.new.

Here's below the result when using BASH

```
arnaud@L340:~/Downloads/Test$ ls
1.webp  2.webp  3.webp  listing.txt
arnaud@L340:~/Downloads/Test$ cat listing.txt 
1.*
3.*
arnaud@L340:~/Downloads/Test$ find $(</home/arnaud/Downloads/Test/listing.txt) -name "*.webp" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.webp}.webp.new"' _ {} \; 
arnaud@L340:~/Downloads/Test$ ls
1.webp.new  2.webp  3.webp.new  listing.txt
arnaud@L340:~/Downloads/Test$
```

=> The 2 files 1.* et 3.* have the new extension.

With ZSH, I get the following error:

```
╭─ ~/Downloads/Test ▓▒░                                                        ░▒▓ ✔  5m 57s  arnaud@L340 
╰─ find $(</home/arnaud/Downloads/Test/listing.txt) -name "*.webp" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.webp}.webp.new"' _ {} \; 
find: ‘1.*’: No such file or directory
find: ‘3.*’: No such file or directory
╭─ ~/Downloads/Test ▓▒░
```

Do you know why it doesn't work with ZSH?
Thank you!

Comment: The rules around double quoting (in particular, whether the result of an unquoted command substitution undergoes word splitting and filename generation) are different between bash and zsh - see for example [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/65304)

Comment: Regardless, the way that you're using `find` doesn't really make sense here - the non-option arguments are supposed to be directories to be searched, not filenames themselves.